# Entity Splitting in EF Core 8

Tags: c#, json, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I am using EF Core version 8 and want to persist an object of CatalogRuleApp in order to implement versioning such that there should be two tables created in the database, one for `RuleApp` and one for multiple `Revisions`, meaning `RuleApp` with unique name can only be preserved once and there can be multiple Revisions holding the Serialized Json state of specific properties (as shown below). Multiple revision are intended because user can pick any revision and update it, creating a new revision.

How to setup this in DbContext class such that one RuleApp should have multiple revisions.

```cs
interface IRevision
{
    public List<RuleFolder> Rules { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public List<DataElement> DataElements { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RuleApp : Entity, IRevision
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public List<RuleFolder> Rules { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public List<DataElement> DataElements { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CatalogRuleApp : RuleApp
{
    public RevisionInfo Revision { get; set; }
    // other properties... //

    public string RevisionJsonState
    {
        get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject((IRevision)RuleApp);
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return;
    
            var revision = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IRevision>(value);
        
            if (revision != null)
            {
                Rules = revision.Rules;
                Entities = revision.Entities;
                RuleApp.DataElements = revision.DataElements;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class RevisionInfo : Entity
{
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public CheckIn CheckedIn { get; set; }
    public CheckOut CheckedOut { get; set; }
}

public class CheckIn : Entity
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}

public class CheckOut : Entity
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}
```

RuleApps

| Id | Name | Created On |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SampleApp | 6/12/2023 |

Revisions

| RuleAppId | Revision | JsonSerializedState (of Rules + Entities + DataElements) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | { Json } |
| 1 | 2 | { Json } |

Based on some research, this seems to be solved by using [Entity Splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting#entity-splitting) but since I am just a beginner in EF Core, I am looking for guidance from the community to address this problem gracefully.

Comment: _"I am using EF Core latest version"_ Always be explicit about exactly which version you are using. If someone views this question in a couple of years and is using EF Core 12, it may not be helpful if answers are specific to EF Core 8.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, why not let the server manage this for you using temporal tables for example

Comment: This is versioning, not table or entity splitting. Trying to use a feature that looks remotely related will only lead to trouble, because the scenarios are too different. In SQL Server the easy way is to use temporal tables. In other databases you can use triggers to store previous row versions to other tables. In EF Core itself you can use [SaveChanges interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-savechanges-interception-for-auditing) to for auditing or saving object versions

Comment: Even temporal tables concept is new for me but is there any other way to simplify the design based on my requirements?